# Fetch from vueJs to Spring Data

Tags: spring, api, vue.js, spring-security, jwt

As part of my studies, I am currently developing a spring/vueJS application.

After installing and configuring Spring Security, everything happens as expected : a token is generated when a user logs in, and I can reuse this token during my requests.

When I try with Postman, everything works for the best.
[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMr6s.png)

But in my front, with Vue, I systematically get a 403 error, even by entering the token manually as here :

```
fetch("http://localhost:9090/userByEmail?email="+this.state.userdata.email,{
            method: 'GET',
            mode : 'no-cors',
            headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json', 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzQGQuYmUiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6W10sImlhdCI6MTYzODc4Mjg1OCwiZXhwIjoxNjM5OTU0ODAwfQ.3NH_UPZpWilgsy5TAhBHE6C8d4KDZq8-ucZisxDK25w'
            }
      })
```

From the error in chrome dev tools, I have the impression that my header 'Authorization' is not taken into consideration.

[chrome dev tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wykCg.png)

Is there a header or something I forgot?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you try without `mode: 'no-cors'` ?

Comment: @Radeanu Yess and then I have : `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9090/userByEmail?email=s@d.be' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: `mode : 'no-cors',` not resolve the problem . You have typical CORS error. It's problem with server config you need to write correct headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`,. What server you use ?